# Como eliminar en cascada en entity framework asp.net mvc

Tags: base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente diagrama relacional

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un problema, al momento de eliminar un registro de la tabla Tbl_Horarios no me deja, porque esta relacionado con mas de un registro de la tabla de Tbl_DetalleHorario.

Como puedo hacer para que al momento de eliminar un registro de la tabla de Tbl_Horarios también me elimine todos los registro que estén relacionados de la tabla de Tbl_DetalleHorario con el registro que quiero borrar de la tabla de Tbl_Horarios.

Estoy utilizando entity framework en asp.net mvc c#

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero darte una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento adecuado del sitio. Por otro lado, tengo una pregunta ¿y el código que hiciste? Sería excelente que edites tu pregunta y agregues el intento, eso nos facilita ayudarte. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo de una clase contexto:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Trabajador> Trabajadores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Trabajador>()
            .HasRequired(d => d.Area)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

De esta forma defines que al elimnar un Area también se eliminarán los Trabajadores que pertenecen a ella.